# Why does hydrolysis of OF2 give a neutral solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, hydrolysis

I found this equation on the internet for the hydrolysis of $\ce{OF2}$: $\ce{OF2 + H2O -> HF + O2}$. So, according to me, $\ce{HF}$ must make generate an acidic instead of neutral solution.

But in JD Lee, it is stated that it is a neutral solution. Why so?

[image: JD Lee screenshot]

Comment: Who says it is not so?

Comment: It is neutral -i found in many books

Comment: Beyond the ocean there is an island inhabited by two-headed people. I saw this in many books. Should I believe them?

Comment: @RafaelNadal we can help you better if you cite the specific books and page numbers. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin sir i had uploaded book snapshot from (j.d lee concise inorganic chemistry )

Comment: OK, I got it. The reaction does indeed produce acid, but it takes some time. Before that, you will have just a solution of OF2, which is neutral.

Comment: @IvanNeretin this reaction is itself a slow reaction and requires temperature of about 200 degree C ,so  it gets proper time to attain its nature till the reaction is fully completed  ....So, it is not the reasons that you have mentioned

Comment: To me, this looks just like what I said: you will only have acid _after_ the reaction, and the reaction is slow.

Comment: @IvanNeretin sorry sir, but the overall reaction is a neutral solution

Comment: This is nonsense. The overall reaction gives HF, which is an acid (and there is nothing to neutralize it), and O2 that simply flies away. The solution after the hydrolysis just can't be neutral, nor does your book say so.

Comment: Hydrolysis and dissolution are different.  The dissolution of OF2 in water gives a neutral solution. Subsequent hydrolysis, which is very slow, eventually produces HF and hence acidic solutions.

Comment: @IanBush But not a strongly acidic one as HF is a weak acid.

Comment: Everyone is comments it is acidic but in my Question Paper answer was neutral

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hydrolysis doesn't give a neutral solution, but the hydrolysis reaction is slow**

Don't confuse *dissolving* something in water with *hydrolysis*. Some chemicals hydrolyse rapidly in water but not OF<sub>2</sub>. Oxygen difluoride will *dissolve* in water forming a neutral solution but will only *slowly* hydrolyse giving a solution containing HF which will be acidic.

So your book is correct, at least in the short term, the *solution* will be neutral.